# I can not access remote desktop which is in a college when I am outside the college through internet

Tags: chrome-remote-desktop

I have configured chrome remote desktop on both my pc and on my college library desktop computer. When I was inside the college I was able to access the desktop remotely .But After I go home I can not access the the desktop computer. When I try to connect to the desktop computer a message is sent to my pc in small pop up.the message is this:
***" unable to reach the remote computer the adminsatrator of that computer may have configured it not to allow connection from out side its local network or it maybe on a network that does not support external connections"**

I wonder if some one can help me !

Answer (score 0):

well, the message is very explicit. To access a remote desktop from outside, you need either explicit accesses to be setup from your home to your college (including your home box access point). But in most of the cases, all you college computers are operation inside a LAN (o VLAN) and you can be provided a VPN access, if the IT dpet whishes so.
So, your best bet is to really contact your IT